# Django contact form: email not sending

Tags: django

I'm currently building a contact form for my website in Django.
The only problem is that the email is not being sent when the form is submitted.
This is the code:

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "c******o@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
```

views.py:

```
sender_name = form.cleaned_data['nome_completo']
            sender_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = "{0} has sent you a new message:\n\n{1}".format(sender_name, form.cleaned_data['messaggio'])

            send_mail('New Enquiry', message, sender_email, ['c******o@gmail.com'])
```

**My thought:**
Since I'm in a virtualenv, when I submit the form, the terminal displays that it was successfully submitted, and gets me back the code right, maybe the email is not sent because of that, or maybe because I'm using a gmail account? Thanks!

Comment: console.EmailBackend is just for development/testing. It doesn't send emails. You need an smtp server for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using an SMTP server, why not use the following backend:

`django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`

Also, if you are using Gmail, make sure of the following:

1. Two-Factor authentication is enabled on account
2. You are using an `app` password.

You can find these on the security tab on your google account page:

https://myaccount.google.com/security

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is with `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`

This outputs emails to your console for debugging instead of actually sending emails. (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#console-backend)

Don't set `EMAIL_BACKEND` to anything for production as it defaults to `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`. Then your EMAIL_HOST settings will take effect and the email should be sent out.